# Configure Postfix to forward mails to other mail addresses (ex gmail)?

Tags: postfix-mta

I have configured Postfix on my Ubuntu server to send/receive mails.

While the sending works perfectly fine but the receiving doesn't. I want to forward all received mail to my gmail account.

My `/etc/postfix/mail.cf` is as follow:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.compzzz.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_domains = compzzz.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = droplet1.compzzz.com, localhost.compzzz.com, localhost, compzzz.com, mail.compzzz.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

And my `/etc/postfix/virtual` is:

```
@compzzz.com ramabc@gmail.com
```

Any mail I send to `abc@compzzz.com`, I receive a delivery failed email with unknown user error.

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: What does the mail log say?

Comment: Log says `User unknown in virtual alias table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't get much help for this query, unfortunately. Therefore, I went through the [postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding) and found the problem finally.

Just commenting the line which declared `mydestination` made it work.

i.e, replace the line

```
mydestination = droplet1.compzzz.com, localhost.compzzz.com, localhost, compzzz.com, mail.compzzz.com
```

with

```
#mydestination = droplet1.compzzz.com, localhost.compzzz.com, localhost, compzzz.com, mail.compzzz.com
```

For forwarding emails to another address (other than your server), `mydestination` parameter isn't required, only `virtual_alias_domains` and `virtual_alias_maps` are required.